# magento site temporally unavailable

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I put my magento site on maiatenance mode whislt I did a back up.

after the back i deleted all the file in the server because i wanted to start afresh because of a database issue.

but to my surprise I am getting an error when i visit the domain even when there are no files on the server.

what could be the problem?

I even deleted the cpanel account from WHM and created from the scratch but anytime i visit the domain, I get that error.

Very strange!!

please see attached.[image]

Comment: Be sure and clear your browsers cache and/or try incognito mode in Chrome to confirm no client side caches are being used instead. Also, if your host has any types of full page caching it could also be the cause, as removing all files from the host should not show such at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a file called `maintenance.flag` on your root of Magento. Delete that file and it should work.